# Upload image to a server (picasa/dropbox/etc) and retrieve the url to save it on my database

Tags: javascript, html, image, web, upload

I'm developing a web application right now and i want to upload an image from a form to an external server like picasa, dropbox or any cloud server that is trustable. Then i want to retrieve the url of the uploaded image and save it to my database using javascript, html or php.

I have done everything (form, web app, database connection).

I only need a guidance guys, so i hope someone who done this before can point me to the right direction.

PD: This app will be used by users, so it should be easy to use for them (upload image, preview, fill form and save form-no account loggin or anything like that)

Thanx and i'm sorry if my english is bad.

Answer (score 1):

it depends of service image, by example dropbox have an API and the PUT method to upload files, this method returns info in JSON format that you can use to store in your own database (https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#files_put).

User Selects a file () >> Then you call the API methods (of the service to use) >> Catch the return data and then call your method to store info in your own DB

Can use [Jquery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to do API calls